# Displaying a default picture when the picture of the profile does not exist using file_exists php

Tags: php, laravel, file

I have an application in native php, and I am trying to upgrade it and use laravel framework. In the user dashboard page, there is a profile picture that is brought from the pictures directory based on the user ID (empid). If the user does not have a profile picture, there is a default picture that is displayed. I used to do it in native php using file_exists method. But I am not sure why it is not working now with laravel.
Here is my code

```
@if (file_exists(URL::asset('assets/img/faces/'.Auth::user()->empid.'.jpeg')))
   <img alt="user-img" class="avatar avatar-xl brround" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/img/faces/'.Auth::user()->empid.'.jpeg') }}">
@else
  <img alt="user-img" class="avatar avatar-xl brround" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/img/faces/default.jpeg') }}">
@endif
```

The code does not enter the if block; all the time the else block is evaluated.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What does `URL::asset('assets/img/faces/'.Auth::user()->empid.'.jpeg')` contain? Does the file exist?

Comment: Yes, the file exists. When I hard code the user id, the picture is shown.

Comment: have you tried `@if (Storage::exists('assets/img/faces/'.auth()->user()->empid.'.jpeg'))`

Answer (score 3):

The mistake you're doing is passing a `URL` to `file_exists` because `URL::asset` returns a full url not a file path so you need to tweak a little bit something like this

```php
$path = 'assets/img/faces/'.Auth::user()->empid.'.jpeg'
file_exists(public_path($path))
```

Your blade code can be simplified if you extracted the logic to a function that returns an avatar, I would place it in your `User` model.

```php
// User.php

/**
 * Get the user's avatar if it exists otherwise gets a default avatar.
 * @return string
 */
public function getAvatar()
{
    $path = 'assets/img/faces/' . Auth::user()->empid . '.jpeg';

    if (file_exists(public_path($path))) {
        return asset($path);
    }

    return asset('assets/img/faces/default.jpeg');
}
```

Then in your blade remove the @if @else block and replace it with this simplified

```
<img alt="user-img" class="avatar avatar-xl brround" src="{{ Auth::user()->getAvatar() }}">
```